# MATLAB - Find all maxima of a function by varying a parameter

Tags: matlab

I have a function in two variables in MATLAB. I want to fix one variable, get the maxima of the resultant function, then change the value of the variable and again get the maxima, and so on. How can I get all the resulting maxima in one step or one vector? The variation in the second variable is a continuous one, not a discrete one.

Comment: What kind of information you need? absolute or relative minima? value or positions?

Comment: What kind of function do you have? A polynomial, a discrete or a continuous scary monster? :)

Answer (score 0):

Some variation of this work for you?

```
function main 

clear all, close all
sizer = floor(rand(1) .* 10 + 1)
X = ceil(rand(sizer,1) .* 10)
Y = floor(rand(sizer,1) .* 10)
Z = Zmax(X, Y, sizer)


    function Z = Zmax(X, Y, sizer)

    Z = zeros(size(sizer));

    for i = 1:1:sizer
        Z(i) = max([X(i), Y(i)]);
    end

    Z = Z';

    end

end
```

You'll probably have to add this to Zmax since your second variable has continuous variation: http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fnval.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, but worked it out. I just varied the variable in a loop and stored the respective maxima in an array. Did the job for me.. :)